# MySQL SELECT inside VALUE + max(ID)+1

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Any idea how can I change max(ID)+1 to select the highest auto increment value from wp_post table. I want to make sure I can choose equivalent of max(ID)+1

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts`(`ID`, `post_author`, `post_title`, `post_status`, `comment_status`,`post_type`)
    VALUES ((SELECT max(ID)+1 FROM wp_posts),1,'name lastname', 'publish', 'closed', 'post_type');
```

Above query has an error, cos it's not possible to select max+1 from the same table where an INSERT statement is set up.

Comment: If the column is auto incremented, why are you setting it in the `select`?  It gets a value automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You suggest that `id` is auto-incremented.  If not, then it should be.  Then you would write the statement as:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts`(`post_author`, `post_title`, `post_status`,
                       `comment_status`,`post_type`)
    VALUES (1, 'name lastname', 'publish', 'closed', 'post_type');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) says use ID as auto-increment here is create table example..

```
CREATE TABLE wp_posts
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
post_author varchar(255) NOT NULL,
post_title varchar(255),
post_status varchar(255),
comment_status varchar(255),
post_type varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Than you can insert as Gordon mentioned..

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts`(`post_author`, `post_title`, `post_status`,
                       `comment_status`,`post_type`)
    VALUES (1, 'name lastname', 'publish', 'closed', 'post_type');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [auto-increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

> The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an auto increment to an existing table to achieve what you are trying to do. `ALTER TABLE wp_posts MODIFY id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Answer (score 0):

set @ID=(SELECT if(max(id) is null,1, max(id)+1) FROM wp_posts);

INSERT INTO `wp_posts`(`ID`, `post_author`, `post_title`, `post_status`, `comment_status`,`post_type`)
    VALUES (@ID,1,'name lastname', 'publish', 'closed', 'post_type');